# Generate HPKP fingerprints for all certificate chain

Tags: openssl, ssl, https

From below command able to generate Base64 pin for only first depth certificate. But need to generate pin for all depth of certificate.

```
openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 -showcerts 
| openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Gives only one key instead of three,

```
cUPcTAZWKaASuYWhhneDttWpY3oBAkE3h2+soZS7sWs=
```

So, how can we generate all three level of pins?

Comment: OpenSSL is only parsing the first certificate. Separate the certificates first, and then run the commands on each certificate. Also see [How to split a PEM file](https://serverfault.com/q/391396/145545) on Server Fault, [How to view all SSL certificates in a bundle?](https://serverfault.com/a/591263/145545) on Ubuntu.SE, [How can I split a CA certificate bundle into separate files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23644473/608639), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I mostly concur with Romeo that you should have the cert files on the server already, if you *do* need to process the multiple certs from one `s_client` you can do something like:

```
 openssl s_client ..... -showcerts \
   | awk '/-----BEGIN/{f="cert."(n++)} f{print>f} /-----END/{f=""}'
 # or input from bundle or chain file
 for c in cert.*; do
   openssl x509 <$c -noout -pubkey .....
 done
 rm cert.* 
 # use better temp name/location if you want
```

Comment: Nice answer. I hope I remember its location to cite it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the issuer from the certificate (CN of issuer). But from this point you should get this certificate by hand, searching on the issuer web site. If you have access to the web server you will find in filesystem the certificates and run your script over the file(s) with CA certificates