# How to distinct parts of a ssl CA bundle

Tags: ssl, certificates

I have a .pem file with four distinct sections. The first is obviously the private key because it says so. The latter three parts however I don't know which is which. This cert has been provided to me and I need to extract the intermediate and root cert to put it in separate .pem files.

I only understand some stuff about all this and I was wondering if there's a good way of displaying the different parts of the bundle to show me what they are.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366898/generate-hpkp-fingerprints-for-all-certificate-chain/ including several links in a comment on the Q

Answer (score 1):

Put all the certificate sections into separate .pem files, then run `openssl x509 -in filename.pem -noout -text` on each of them. (Replace `filename.pem` with the actual filename, of course.) The "Subject" line will show the identity of each certificate, and the "Issuer" line will identify the corresponding higher-level certificate. If Subject = Issuer, you're looking at a root certificate or some other self-signed certificate.

Defining a command alias like this can make the output a little bit more concise:

```
alias viewcert='openssl x509 -noout -text -certopt no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_header,ext_parse -nameopt multiline,show_type -in'
```

Put the above line in your `~/.bashrc` or similar, then open a new session and run `viewcert filename.pem` on each certificate.

Comment: thank you very much!